# Cannot uninstall the Web browser

Tags: epiphany

I've tried uninstalling epiphany but I get "package not installed"
I tried from Applications menu and I got "Application state not set as installed in AppCenter for package: GNOME Web"

I looked for "Gnome Web" in Synaptics and could not find it.

Looking online didn't help.

I just want to uninstall it, it does not work, I get "Something went wrong while displaying this page. Please reload or visit a different page to continue." in *every* tab.

I reinstalled Elementary OS 6 and Web stopped working 10 min in.

At the same time Midori and Edge are rock solid.

Comment: The Gnome Web package is used by a number of applications in Elementary OS, so uninstalling it would break a great many things. Why are you trying to remove it from the system rather than setting something else as the default browser?

Comment: Hi Matigo, if I'm not using an app in my machine I want it gone, no clutter around :-)

Comment: If this is an ideal you are strongly bound to, then Elementary OS — and most other Ubuntu-based derivatives — may not be for you 

Comment: I guess I'll learn to love her as it is, with her virtues and defects. It seems she also tends to get fatter with time :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got epiphany working again, after long searches in the internet, by installing the nvidia drivers for my machine.
Unfortunately I cant find the instructions again but it was basically finding out what nvidia version I had and installing them via terminal.

That made epiphany work again.

Update: The AppCenter now has an Uninstall button so that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, most of Elementary's default applications are flatpaks, since at least Odin.  You can search for them with 'flatpak search PKGNAME'.  I uninstalled the default web browser with 'flatpak remove epiphany'.  And yeah, you can do it with the AppCenter which is pretty amazing :D.  You shouldn't break anything as the required lib files are independent from the rest of the natively installed libs on your system.